# vector subscript out of range during compiling

Tags: c++

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

vector<vector<int>> normal;
vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
vector<int>::iterator col;

for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
         normal[i].push_back(j);

    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what l am doing wrong? during my compiling I got the error "Vector subscript out of range"

Comment: Pretty sure that isn't a compiler error.

Comment: It is probably a run time error. But this would be straightforward for static analysis to catch so it might be a compiler error in theory.

Comment: look close at this part normal[i].push_back(j); you are adding elements to the vector that doesn't exit. try changing your code to this and see what happens vector<vector<int>> normal {9}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't put anything into `normal`. It sits as an empty vector until you put something into it.

You can fix this problem by giving it a new value each iteration

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    normal.push_back(vector<int>());
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         normal[i].push_back(j);
    }
}
```

Also, your `i` and `j` were being initialized to `1`, but I'm fairly certain you meant `0`. I addressed this in my snippet.

Comment: Or better; don't use nested `vector`s for this use-case.  Consider a `std::vector<std::array<int,10>>` for a vector of flat arrays.  You don't need pointers to pointers and all your rows are the same length so you don't need a separate memory allocation for each one.

Answer (score 10):

You never add any elements to `normal` before trying to use `normal[i]`.

Answer (score 6):

Vector normal is empty.
You can initialize vector as follow.

```
vector<vector<int>> normal(10, vector<int>());
```

Comment: Underrated answer. My answer wouldn't be necessary if this was implemented. This is also much faster as you don't need to reallocate every iteration.

Comment: @BrandonDyer: If you care about performance, you wouldn't use nested vectors at all here.  Use a 2D array, or use `std::array`, or maybe a `std::vector<std::array<int.10>> normal(10)` if you want to be able to grow more rows.  Reserving space before `push_back` makes sense; zero-initializing with a constructor doesn't really make as much sense.  The compiler would have to optimize away the zero-init if you only want to write the memory once.