# Trying to read strings from a file into an unsigned char vector

Tags: c++, vector, char

I'm really new to coding yet, so bear with me.
When running the following code, I always get a fatal error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: [program name]
File: [MS VS path]\include\vector
Line: 1502

Expression: vector subscript out of range
```

What could be causing this?

```
string temp1;
stringstream temp2;
unsigned char temp3;
vector<vector<unsigned char>>vectorname;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                Datei >> temp1; // copies file into string
                temp2 << temp1; //copies string into streamstring
                temp2 >> temp3; //copies streamstring into unsigned char
                vectorname[i][j] = temp3 //sets the unigned char as value at the i,j, position.

            }
        }
```

Comment: `Bild[i][j] = temp3 //sets the unigned char as value at the i,j, position.` goes out of range as the message tells you. Error messages should be text not images btw.

Comment: Yes. But why would it go out of range. I used used 5x5 as a sample size, but the actual file is much larger, which shouldnt be a problem. And the vector should grow dynamically right ?   Edit: sorry about the picture

Comment: @m0xpl0x The vector grows dynamically when using certain methods like [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), but not methods like `operator[]`.  I suggest you take a look at the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Note that you can use vector's [sized constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) to pre-allocate space for your elements.  Or even better, since you are using a constant size of 5x5, you can use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, whose size is fixed at compile-time.

Comment: *And the vector should grow dynamically right ?*.  Call `push_back`, `resize`, or `insert`.  Using `[ ]` does not make a vector grow. -- it is used to *access pre-existing* elements.

Comment: @0x5453 yes i just used 5x5 for debugging but later on i´d like to be able to change the vector size. How would you use push_back with [i], [j] and the value of temp3 syntactically speaking, because i tried this as well, but never got it right

Comment: @m0xpl0x *How would you use push_back* -- If you have a `std::vector<T>`, how do you add a new `T` to the vector?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie would that be T.push_back ( vector<unsigned char> (temp3)) ?

Comment: When saying `std::vector<T>`, the `T` could be any type, i.e. `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<double>`, `std::vector<Thing>`, etc.  So given that, if you have a `std::vector<T> vect;`, how do you add a new `T` to the vector `vect`?  Using `vect[1]` doesn't add a new item, again that accesses the entry at `vect[1]`.  So using `[ ]` isn't correct.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that would be vect.push_back ( T ) right ?

Comment: So now replace the `T` with the type it really is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie vect.push_back ( unsigned char) ?

Comment: You need to look closely at your definitions.  `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>`.  What is the `T` for the "outer" vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vector subscript out of range during compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503902/vector-subscript-out-of-range-during-compiling)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is the T = std::vector<unsigned char>?

Comment: Yes, see my answer.  You basically build the vector in "blocks".  Get a new vector, add items to it, get a new vector add items to it, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorry to be such a hardcase, but in the inner loop, if i got i ´vect.back().push_back(j) ´the j is just filling the inner vector with unsigned integers of j right? couldnt i then instead add the temporay value of temp3 like so ´vect.back().push_back(temp) ´     And if yes, why cant i put out ´cout << vect.at(i).at(j) << endl;

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  My answer was a general illustration of what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically grow the 2D vector in the loop, you need to add a new inner vector, and given the new inner vector, add items to it.

Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> vectorname;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        // add a new vector to the outer std::vector
        vectorname.push_back(vector<unsigned char>());

        // now add data to the newly added vector. The `back()` returns
        // a reference to the last added vector
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            vectorname.back().push_back(j);    
    }
}
```